# How to wait for an api request to return a response?

Tags: java, api-testing, rest-api

We use a proprietary framework based on the [REST-assured](http://rest-assured.io/) library and [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/) to automate API testing for our REST web services. I saw some api testing code which uses `Thread.sleep(n seconds)` to wait for a response to be returned. This seems wrong to me because the response times can vary. I believe that there should be a better way to wait for a response, i.e. wait only as much as necessary. Maybe I could poll every few milliseconds, or by use an observer (test)-observed (api) design pattern, or something else. I am not sure.

How do I wait for an api to return a response ?

This is what the code looks like:

```
@Test
public void doApiTesting() throws Exception 
{   
    framework.loginUser(User);
    framework.createNewData();//Takes some time.
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP is a synchronous protocol* so active polling is not an option. You need to wait until client receives response or request times out. There are two ways to constrain synchronous behaviour with timeout.

One is to set a timeout for receiving a response. REST-Assured uses Apache HTTP Client for which you can set `http.socket.timeout` and `http.connection.timeout`. See answers for [Apache HttpClient timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764035/apache-httpclient-timeout) and [Apache HTTP Client documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html).

Another solution is to set a certain timeout for a block of your test code:

```
new TimeLimitedCodeBlock(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) { 

  @Override 
  public void codeBlock() {
     framework.createNewData();//Takes some time.
  }

}.run();
```

`TimeLimitedCodeBlock` is described in answers to [Java: set timeout on a certain block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715235/java-set-timeout-on-a-certain-block-of-code).

***Synchronous communication**

> In program-to-program communication, synchronous communication
>   requires that each end of an exchange of communication respond in turn
>   without initiating a new communication. A typical activity that might
>   use a synchronous protocol would be a transmission of files from one
>   point to another. As each transmission is received, a response is
>   returned indicating success or the need to resend. Each successive
>   transmission of data requires a response to the previous transmission
>   before a new one can be initiated.

**EDIT**

Active polling is not an option, because waiting for HTTP Response is synchronous: it blocks the current thread until response is received. `TimeLimitedCodeBlock` class I mentioned waits for HTTP Response in a separate thread. The separate thread terminates when HTTP Response is received or time out passes. Instead of actively checking (polling) if a separate thread has received HTTP response, `TimeLimitedCodeBlock` is waiting for a separate thread to terminate.

Comment: Could you please explain why polling is not an option in synchronous protocols such as HTTP ? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnSink Hopefully, I explained. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom wait method for the same purpose. You can create a similar one to match your needs. The method below waits atMost TIMEOUT seconds or until the API response has the expectedString

```
public String waitUntilStringFoundInResponse(String apiPath, HashMap<String, String> parameters, String findMe, int TIMEOUT) throws Exception {
    String result = null;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < TIMEOUT) {
        result = postHttpsRequest(apiPath, parameters);
        if (result.contains(findMe)) {
            break;
        } else {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            ++i;
            if (i == TIMEOUT) {
                throw new TimeoutException("Timed out after waiting for " + i + " seconds");
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

There is also a method in `org.awaitility.Awaitility` that can be used for the same purpose, but the method runs on a different thread, so I was having session issues. [Here is the documentation](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage) for that if you prefer to use that instead of writing a custom one.

Comment: I guess `postHttpsRequest` is a synchronous call to REST API. The problem with this solution is that it will repeat POST Request multiple times (maximually `TIMEOUT` times). Awaitlity works in a similar way. It performs active polling . That's why Awaitlity is called "DSL" for synchronizing asynchronous operations, while HTTP is basically synchronous protocol.

Comment: right. That is what I wanted.  i.e. I wanted to wait until the API response contained particular string. eg. I am doing a search on something and there is a delay in getting the results. So the API response might not have the expected string until after waiting for a few seconds. So I keep executing the POST request until the response has the String. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but this is not what the OP asked for :-)

Comment: Oops sorry about that. I just read the question again and realized that myself. I will delete my answer :)

Comment: Anu, perhaps you don't need to delete it because the discussion below 
 your answer clarifies the problem better.